# KeePass XC Database is not syncronised in Ubuntu 20.04 with Google

Tags: 20.04, google-drive, keepassxc

Hello I have a small problem. My KeePassXC does not seem to write the database to Google Drive. If I save a new password via Windows (Backup & Sync Client), I can see it a short time later in Ubuntu! If I save a new password in Ubuntu, the entry disappears again after closing and opening KeePass XC.

I have tried 2 Keepass versions
2.4.3 (Ubuntu Rep. apt-get install)
2.6.4 Snap installation

2.4.3 - There I can open the database but writing new entries does not work.

2.6.4 - Here I can't select the database in Google Drive.

The Google account is normally connected via Ubuntu Online Accounts. Copying files manually into Google Drive works without problems. There is also enough memory in Google Drive

Do you have any idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: It is not a KeepassXC problem, but a problem with the Google drive client, in this case the system provided online accounts. It could be a delay in the synchronisation: could you try whether it does not get updated after a certain period?

Comment: I do not believe that it is due to a delay! I will check it for safety but again. but 5 to 10 min dan apparently not enough!

Comment: I have rather the feeling that it only works if you do it with the Ubuntu file manager. funnily enough, in the current KeePassXC version is no longer the possibility to select online accounts as online storage!